# chrome.proxy.settings how to add param like country and session id?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

I have a list of proxies like:

```
host:port:username:password_country-de
```

If I don't set `country-de`, then I get random Countries. How to set config for country?

My code:

```
if (request.type === 'setProxy') {
        const proxyParts = request.selectedProxy.split(':');
        const host = proxyParts[0];
        const port = parseInt(proxyParts[1]);
        const username = proxyParts[2];
        const password = proxyParts[3].split('_')[0];
        const country = 'de';
        USERNAME = username;
        PASSWORD = password;

        const config = {
            mode: 'fixed_servers',
            rules: {
                singleProxy: {
                    scheme: 'http',
                    host: host,
                    port: port,
                },
            },
        };
        chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'},
            function () {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```